# Manifest file in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, file, manifest

I have a problem with my Asp.net project I can't add manifest file. I'm using VS 2013. When I click "Add new item" I don't find "Application manifest file" item. Can somebody help me?

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Why do you need it? Mostly they are used for desktop applications, but not for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

This file is located under AddNewItem popup box under General Category (Visual Basic or Visual C#).[image]

Comment: I don't have "General" tab, I have only Visual Basic and C# :(